# A verb for becoming curious as a result of an event?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb to convey “becoming curious as a result of something having taken place”. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to **pique** someone's curiosity or interest

[from the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pique-sb-s-curiosity-interest-etc)

to make someone interested in something and want to know more about it:

The noise continued, *piquing* her curiosity.

---

intrigued

[From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intrigued)

having one's interest, desire, or curiosity strongly aroused

Cricket was *intrigued*, but I decided it wasn't good enough for her, and we moved to the sprawling Marriott resort, a complex of pretty lawns and pools with swim-up bars on the Chao Phraya river. —Food and Wine

And all the time she laughed, he watched, a smile quirking the corners of his mouth, as though he were both *intrigued* and delighted that he had done this, that he had made her laugh so suddenly and uncontrollably. —Rachel Joyce

Comment: I'm interested in a word which encompasses `to pique one's curiosity` singly, think similar to the make-believe word `to be "curiousized"`

Comment: To be 'interested'?